# A convenient class of sets of sets, can it be described in another way?

Tags: set-theory

I will call an *almost universe* a union of powersets closed on binary unions.

A good thing about almost universes that both Grotendick universes and powersets are almost universes. So, it seems a useful term to introduce, because no more need to prove a theorem for both powersets and for Grotendick universes.

Question: Any other equivalent way to define almost universes?

Comment: Almost universes are classes of sets closed both for binary union and for taking a subset. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously every almost universe is a class of sets closed both for binary union and for taking a subset.

Reversely, take a class of sets closed both for binary union and for taking a subset. It is a union of all powersets of its members.

By the way, almost universes are closed regarding arbitrary intersections.